# Bhoechie tab not working after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using Bhoechie tab which is made with JQuery when the page loads, everything works perfectly. However, after I make my ajax request which changes my tab menu content, it doesn't work properly anymore. What can I do to make it work at all times?

Here is my tab menu jQuery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div.bhoechie-tab-menu>div.list-group>a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings('a.active').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var index = $(this).index();
    $("div.bhoechie-tab>div.bhoechie-tab-content").removeClass("active");
    $("div.bhoechie-tab>div.bhoechie-tab-content").eq(index).addClass("active");
});
});
```

Tab Html

```
<div class="bhoechie-tab-menu">
<div class="list-group">
<a href="#" class="list-group-item active "> TAB1 </a> <a href="#" class="list-group-item "> TAB2 </a> <a href="#" class="list-group-item ">TAB1 </a> <a href="#" class="list-group-item"> TAB1 </a>
<div>
<div class="bhoechie-tab">
  <div class="bhoechie-tab-content active">
    <section> </section>
  </div>
  <div class="bhoechie-tab-content">
    <section> </section>
  </div>
  <div class="bhoechie-tab-content">
    <section> </section>
  </div>
  <div class="bhoechie-tab-content">
    <section> </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

AJAX

```
function showVehicle(id){
var container = $("#id_administrator");
var form = "";
$.ajax({
    url: "forms/show.php",          
    type:'POST',
    data:{"vreg":id},
    async:false,
    }).done(function(data){
        form= data;
    });

 container.html(form);
}
```

Comment: From where you invoke AJAX?

Comment: Do i need destroy or refresh for a AJAX load ? If yes please do let me know.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - `$.ajax` returns a XHR object with promise interface. So its like a promise. Now if you have your `showVehicle()` just in your js file and dont call it, it doesn't do anything, just sits in memory

Comment: showVehicle(id) is my data table and from there i am calling the function to fill data on the php page.

Comment: So call it again whenever needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script also need to call it from AJAX so just modify the script like this mentioned below, so that it would run on AJAX load.

```
function showVehicle(id){
var container = $("#id_administrator");
var form = "";
$.ajax({
  url: "forms/show.php",          
  type:'POST',
  data:{"vreg":id},
  async:false,
}).done(function(data){
    form= data;
});

container.html(form);

$("div.bhoechie-tab-menu>div.list-group>a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).siblings('a.active').removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  var index = $(this).index();
  $("div.bhoechie-tab>div.bhoechie-tab-content").removeClass("active");
  $("div.bhoechie-tab>div.bhoechie-tab-content").eq(index).addClass("active");
});

}
```

please check and do let me know in comment.